# Playback audio failed on macOS using swift language

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

**Goal: Play .m4a audio file that was recorded on mic**

**Following code is to record audio from mic**

```
public func startRecording() {
        let input = audioEngine.inputNode
        let bus = 0
        let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: bus)
        
        let outputURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("recorded123.m4a")
        print("writing to \(outputURL)")
        do {
            outputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputURL, settings: inputFormat.settings, commonFormat: inputFormat.commonFormat, interleaved: inputFormat.isInterleaved)
            
            input.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) in
                try? self.outputFile?.write(from: buffer)
            }
            
            try audioEngine.start()
            recording = true
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**Following code is to playback the recorded audio**

```
func startPlayback(audio: URL) {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audio)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            audioPlayer.play()
            
            isPlaying = true
        } catch {
            print("Playback failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

**The above code works for .caf filetype but when I changed it to .m4a type it fails to play** and prints *Playback failed The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)*

Any help is highly appreciated

*My assumption is that the audio is not properly recorded in startRecording method*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are recording the audio in the correct format:

To specify the output file type as .m4a, you should configure the output format settings accordingly. Here's how you can modify the startRecording function:

```swift
public func startRecording() {
    let input = audioEngine.inputNode
    let bus = 0
    let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: bus)
    
    let outputURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("recorded123.m4a")
    print("writing to \(outputURL)")
    
    let outputFormatSettings: [String: Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0
    ]

    do {
        outputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputURL, settings: outputFormatSettings)
        
        input.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) in
            try? self.outputFile?.write(from: buffer)
        }
        
        try audioEngine.start()
        recording = true
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```